# How to prove the normality of space using open surjective map

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem in this question in General topology I cannot even start to prove it, Is it possible that there is a mistake and the Question should be bijective?
[image]

Question:
Let $f:X \to Y$ be open surjection, $X$ is Normal, Show that $Y$ is normal.

Comment: I fixed your image embedding, but you'll get a better response if you typeset its contents instead.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm new to math.stacks and this was my first post.

Comment: Please give the precise definition of "normal".

Comment: Space X is normal if for every two disjoint closed sets A,B
There is 2 disjoint open sets U,V containing A,B respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the intention of the problem-writer was, but this problem is asking you to prove something that is false.

Consider $X=\mathbb R\times \{0,1\}$ with the Euclidean topology from $\mathbb R^2$, let $Y=X/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation identifying $(x,0)$ and $(x,1)$, for $x\neq 0$, and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be the quotient map.

Note that for any open $U\subseteq X$, $f^{-1}(f(U))$ is open as well (it suffices to verify this for open intervals in either line), so the quotient map is open.

On the other hand, the quotient space, which is [the line with two origins](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000083) endpoints, is certainly not normal (it is $T_1$ and not Hausdorff).

(Note that it is $T_1$ since equivalence classes are closed, and fails to be $T_2$ since every saturated neighborhood of $(0,0)$ intersects every saturated neighborhood of $(0,1)$, so the two origins may not be separated in the quotient by disjoint neighborhoods.)

##### Remark.

Regarding the possibility that the question meant to suppose $f$ is bijective, this is still not correct, if continuity of $f$ is not assumed.
To disprove it one then must find a normal $X$ with a finer topology that is not normal.

If your definition of "normal" does not require $T_1$, this is easy, since any non-normal space has a coarser normal topology, namely the indiscrete topology.

But this is kind of silly, so let's suppose you define normal to require $T_1$.  Even then, any submetrizable (has a coarser metrizable topology) non-normal space will do, and a search of pi-base comes with [several examples](https://%20https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Submetrizable%20%2B%7ENormal):

The [indiscrete rational extensoion of the reals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000058), the [indiscrete irrational extension of the reals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000059), and the [Sorgenfrey Plane](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000076).

Finally, if the question wanted $f$ to be a continuous bijection, then of course the result is true and trivial, as a continuous open bijection preserves every topological property.